# why i couldnot use onGUIInit in my installer script?

Tags: nsis

I am trying to use onGUIInit function on my installer script but while compiling the script i am getting error that onguiinit already exits but there is only one onguiinit

ERROR:

```
Function: ".onGUIInit"
Error: Function named ".onGUIInit" already exists.
```

Comment: If you are using MUI or some other toolkit you need to use the correct define since there can only be one real .onGuiInit function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myonguiinit
!include MUI.nsh

Function myonguiinit
FunctionEnd
```